# Getting CFQUERY Timeout but only on one computer

Tags: windows, windows-7, coldfusion

This is a strange one, I am do a cfquery and very consistatly I am getting a CFQUERY timeout error.  I goto a different computer, exact same user login, exact same query, and I get no timeouts.  I am suspecting an Internet Setting in Windows 7 causing this headache, but not sure which setting.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If it works fine on other computers, yes, it's a client issue.

Try a different browser on the timeout query machine.

Answer (score 0):

Clear all of your caches, client and ColdFusion template cache.  Are you setting client side cookies?

Comment: Yes, I am using client side cookies.

Comment: and after you cleared all your caches & cookies.. if nothing you are going to have to post some code.